# How do I change the password of a sql user that has a blank name?

Tags: sql, h2

My H2 database's root user's name is completely blank so when I try to use the password change command on it, but it doesn't work. I receive this error every time I try:

```
Syntax error in SQL statement "ALTER USER   SET PASSWORD[*] 'newpassword'"; expected "SET, RENAME, ADMIN"; SQL statement:
ALTER USER   SET PASSWORD 'newpassword' [42001-195] 42001/42001
```

I think it may be possible to alter it using the user's ID (13) but I have no idea how to go about that. I've also tried putting '' as the user which didn't work.

Comment: Do you know SQL `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Do you have just one user with blank name?

Comment: Yeah I do running `UPDATE INFORMATION_SCHEMA.USERS SET NAME='Admin' WHERE ID=13` returns this error `Feature not supported: "META"; SQL statement:
UPDATE INFORMATION_SCHEMA.USERS SET NAME='Admin' WHERE ID=13 [50100-195] HYC00/50100`

Comment: And here is a screenshot of my Users table http://prntscr.com/ggaf02

Answer (score 0):

If the user name is truly blank the following should work:

```
ALTER USER "" SET PASSWORD 'newPass';
```

Similarly to change it to a more normal name:

```
ALTER USER "" RENAME TO WHATEVER;
```

It's also possible that somebody decided to play an even bigger trick on you and name the user
 `"  "`(2 spaces) or some other name that consists of whitespaces, you can check it by copying the name to an editor that can show whitespaces. If this is the case you need to put the name exactly as is in the double quotes.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
ALTER USER user_ID SET PASSWORD 'rioyxlgt'
```

Comment: Syntax error in SQL statement "ALTER USER 13[*] SET PASSWORD 'rioyxlgt'"; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
ALTER USER 13 SET PASSWORD 'rioyxlgt' [42001-195]